# How to reference other columns in an ifelse using dplyr mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Dataset example is below. When temp.change == 0, I would like to have R just copy the status of the cell above in column X into a new column. I have created another column, shifting the data in column X down to reference it. In otherwords, if temp.change == 0, then make X = X_shifted. I realize that if there are multiple 0's in a row, this also might be an issue with this method. The binary X column is the result of many ifelse statements about column temp.change

```
temp.change     X   X_shifted
9.5             1     NA
1               1     1
-0.5            1     1
-1              0     1
-0.5            0     0
0               1     0
0               1     1
3               1     1          
0               0     1          
1               1     0
```

Is there a way to reference another column in an ifelse statement? I would prefer to try to find a way to do so using `dplyr`, since I have a very large dataset and it is rather quick. I have tried the code below, and a few non dplyr methods without any success.

```
  mutate(X_fixed = ifelse(temp.change_prev==0, X_shifted, X))
```

Expected result:

```
temp.change     X   X_shifted  X_fixed
9.5             1     NA         1
1               1     1          1
-0.5            1     1          1
-1              0     1          0
-0.5            0     0          0
0               1     0          0
0               1     1          0
3               1     1          1
0               0     1          1
1               1     0          1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `X_shifted` you can use `lag` which gives you the previous value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(x_fixed = ifelse(temp.change == 0, lag(X), X))
```

Or if we need `X` from last non-zero value of `temp.change` we could use :

```
df %>%
  mutate(X_fixed = replace(X, temp.change == 0,NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(X_fixed)

#   temp.change X X_fixed
#1          9.5 1       1
#2          1.0 1       1
#3         -0.5 1       1
#4         -1.0 0       0
#5         -0.5 0       0
#6          0.0 1       0
#7          0.0 1       0
#8          3.0 1       1
#9          0.0 0       1
#10         1.0 1       1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(temp.change = c(9.5, 1, -0.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 1), X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, the second portion of code was what I was looking to do. I was able to use that info to also take out 0.5's and -0.5's.